# Issues with two way data binding between service and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my data factory below, which returns a promise

```
.factory('DataService', function($http, $document, CreatorService) {
    promise = null;
    jsonData = null;

        return {
            getJsonDataFromApi: function () {
                    promise = $http.get('/test');
                    return promise;
                }
            }
            getJsonData: function () {
                return jsonData;
            },
            setJsonData: function (data) {
                jsonData = data;
            }
    }
```

My controller makes use of this service as follows

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, DataService,    StyleService, CreatorService) {

$scope.dataService = DataService;

$scope.dataService.getJsonDataFromApi().success(function (data) {
    $scope.dataService.setJsonData(data['content']);
    $scope.jsonData = $scope.dataService.getJsonData();
```

As you can see, I'm trying to bind `$scope.jsonData` to the data service `jsonData` object via `$scope.jsonData = $scope.dataService.getJsonData();` but this doesn't seem to work.

If I update the value of `$scope.jsonData()`, the value returned by `$scope.dataService.getJsonData()` doesn't change.

For example, if I do

```
    $scope.jsonData = {};

    console.log($scope.jsonData);
    console.log($scope.dataService.getJsonData());
```

The output is

```
{}
Object{...}
```

I would have expected them to be the same.  I can't seem to get my service object to update if I change my controller scope object, nor can I get my controller scope object to update if I make a change to the service object.  I want to avoid using watches.

Comment: From where you are invoking controller function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way data binding is for binding with your `$scope` and views. Not for controller and services. So if you really need something like this, then you need to `$watch` and set the data in service everytime it changes.

Comment: Would I have to set up two watches: one to watch for changes on the scope object which then updates the service object, and then another watch on the service object which updates the scope object?

Comment: If you do this for caching your result, then you can set your data in your `getJsonDataFromApi` method, after the promise resolves like: `$http.get('/test').then(function(successResponse) { jsonData = successResponse };`

Now you can add an `if` statement in your `getJsonDataFromApi` method: `if(jsonData) return jsonData`. So now you can call `getJsonDataFromApi` method how much you want, it will fire the request one time.

Comment: If your reason is not caching, explain why you need it, and I will try to find an "angular-way" to accomplish it.

Comment: I download my json data via the API, then I want to store it as a local object in my data service.  I then have a main controller which makes the json data available to my view.  My view renders the json data into html elements, and then I have the ability to alter the html elements (which are now bound to the json data).  Changes to my html need to alter the service object.  I have other controllers which need to edit the same service object.  Any change that is made to my service json object via any of the controllers needs to be reflected in my main view.

Comment: You can set a `$watch` like this: `$scope.$watch(function() { return myService.getJsonData();}, jsonDataChangedCallback);` However it costs a lot. So you may think of storing your common data in your `$rootScope`. So it will be available in all your views.

Comment: ah ok, I wasn't aware that using the $rootScope was the "angular" way of storing common data, but it seems more sensible than having a bunch of taxing watches everywhere.  Thanks very much.